# Using Foundation-CLI / Gulp on Multiple Machines

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, zurb-foundation

I'm working on a project using foundation for sites across multiple computers. I've installed foundation via the command line app (version 2.1.0). My project folder is synced via dropbox and if I run "foundation build" or "foundation watch" on the original machine I created the project on, it works fine.

However, when I attempt to run "foundation watch" on my second computer (with the same versions of foundation-cli and gulp), I get this error. The only difference is one computer has node 5.7.0 and the other has 5.0.0. Everything else (foundation-cli, bower, gulp) are all running identical versions. Any ideas how I can resolve this? Thanks.

Here's the error:

```
> foundation-sites-template@1.0.0 start /Users/nick/Dropbox/Sync/Web Site/www/wp-content/themes/foundation 
> gulp 
module.js:339 
throw err; 
^ 
Error: Cannot find module '../lib/completion' 
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15) 
at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25) 
at Module.require (module.js:366:17) 
at require (module.js:385:17) 
at Object. (/Users/nick/Dropbox/Sync/Web Site/www/wp-
content/themes/foundation/node_modules/.bin/gulp:13:18) 
at Module._compile (module.js:425:26) 
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10) 
at Module.load (module.js:356:32) 
at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12) 
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10) 
Error: foundation-sites-template@1.0.0 start: `gulp` 
Exit status 1 
at EventEmitter. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/foundation-
cli/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:214:16) 
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13) 
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7) 
at ChildProcess. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/foundation- 
cli/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14) 
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13) 
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7) 
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16) 
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
```

EDIT: I've updated to node 5.7.0 on my other computer, so the versions are the same everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I can use it on multiple computers. You just have to delete the `node_modules` folder (e.g., `rm -r node_modules`), then when you want to use on the other machine do `npm install` to get the node modules back for that environment. This is slightly annoying because there are so many files to sync when doing this over Dropbox or NextCloud.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with gulp's package. I had the same error (not using foundation though) and re-installing gulp after an "npm cache clean" fixed it for me, you didn't mention trying that already.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. My solution was to just use a Vagrant virtual machine, install all of this on it, and sync the box itself via Dropbox.